# Determining four rational numbers, given their pairwise sums

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> The pairwise sums of four weights (rational numbers) are: 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16. What are the four weights?

I tried intuitively solving as well as making equations to solve it. If we assume weights in ascending order as: A, B, C, D, then the smallest two weights should sum to 6 (A + B = 6), and the largest two should sum to 16 (C + D = 16).

We can't comment on the order of the rest of the pairs. I tried hit and trial approach with some pairs and working on 4 equations at a time, but I haven't been able to get values which fit all 6 equations.

What would be be a good way to solve this?

Comment: Label the weights as $a<b<c<d$.  Then $a+b=6$ and $c+d=16$.  That lets you eliminate two variables right at the start.  So now you are just down to $a,d$ (say) and you can work from there.  May have to consider cases as you don't instantly know what pair each of the sums corresponds to, but at least you know some.

Comment: Yes @lulu I got that far, as I wrote in my description

Comment: (Assuming you've done enough hit and trial attempts to be frustrated) Perhaps try proving that there are no such 4 weights? EG What is $a+b+c+d$? (Calculate it in 2 different ways and arrive at a contradiction) $\quad$ OR What is $b-c$? (Likewise arrive at a contradiction)

Comment: Well, you do get some of the other pair sums.  $d+b=15$, say.    It's just a matter of trying things.

Comment: Are you sure of $15$? Isn't it rather $14$? (otherwise there is no solution).

Comment: Indeed, a little playing around quickly shows that the system can't be solved.

Comment: @lulu I did try at least 5-6 times with different combinations :( some of the values just don't fit

Comment: Yes, and that shows that the system is not solvable.

Comment: @AnneBauval yes I thought it was 14 too! And also asked the person who sent this question, but she said it's right

Comment: See _The combinatorial Radon transform modulo the symmetric group_ https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/019688589190027G

Comment: The numbers are $[ 2 , 4 , 6 , 10 ]$ : The Question has a "typo" : $15$ must be $14$ : Everything works out with the given Solution & the Corrected Question !

Comment: An obvious issue with a single odd sum and the rest even is one pair is of different parities, but none of the others pairs are.

Comment: @Prem That's only one possible set, for instance $[1, 5, 7, 9]$ also works.

Answer (score 15):

Let the weights be $A,B,C,D$ and WLOG assume $A\le B\le C\le D$. You have already concluded that $A+B=6, C+D=16$.

The second smallest sum must be $8=A+C$. Namely, each of the remaining four sums $A+D, B+C, B+D, C+D$ can be easily proven to be $\ge A+C$. Similarly, the second largest sum must be $15=B+D$.

However, this gives us contradiction as $A+B+C+D=(A+B)+(C+D)=6+16=22$ but also $A+B+C+D=(A+C)+(B+D)=8+15=23$.

Therefore, no such weights exist.

Comment: Note: You can find $3(a+b+c+d)$ by summing up all 6 weights.

Comment: Note that if you are given a different collection of weights this argument applies in exactly the same way. As this gives 4 independent equations for 4 unknowns this will give you the solution if one exists.

Comment: If the six sums are $s_1 \le s_2 \le s_3 \le s_4 \le s_5 \le s_6$ then you need $s_1+s_6=s_2+s_5 = s_3+s_4$

Comment: @CalvinLin Which also gives another way to determine no such weights exist: the sum of the weights is 67, which isn't divisble by 3.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Not quite immediately, unless you additionally prove that the weights must be half-integers.

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh, my mistake, I was thinking they had to be integer weights.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, if you have $2n$ weights and the sums of the weights of any $n$ can be written as:

$$w_1\leq w_2\leq \cdots \leq w_{K},$$ where $K=\binom{2n}n,$ then $w_{j}+w_{K+1-j}$ must be constant as $j=1,2,\dots,K.$

In your case, since $w_1+w_6=6+16=22$ and $w_2+w_5=8+15=23,$ there can be no solution.

---

Even more generally, if we have $m$ weights $u_1,\dots,u_m$ and a set $J$ of subsets of $\{1,\dots,m\}$ which is closed under complements, and we sort the weights $w_S=\sum_{i\in S} u_i$ for each $S\in J$ as $w_1\leq w_2\leq \cdots \leq w_{|J|}$ we again get that $w_{j}+w_{|J|+1-j}$ must be constant.

Answer (score 4):

$A+B+C+D=6+16=22$ and
$$\{A+C,A+D,B+C,B+D\}=\{8,10,12,15\}$$
is impossible, because the four numbers on the RHS cannot be split into two pairs with sum $22.$ The pair containing $15$ will always have an odd sum.

Answer (score 4):

From the conditions, since you assumed that $A_1\leq A_2\leq A_3\leq A_4$, we can conclude that $A_1+A_2=6$, $A_3+A_4=16$, $A_1+A_3=8$ and $A_2+A_4=15$. This gives $A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4=22=23$, which is a contradiction. Hence, it is impossible to satisfy the conditions in the question.

Comment: This is more or less the same as @StinkingBishop's answer (with less justifications).

Comment: The other answer was written first, so I guess that's that. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: Hm, well it I guess it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: It does matter, in that if you just repeat (without offering anything new with it) an answer that already existed before you started posting, then you would be just wasting peoples time, and that deserves a downvote. However, you were only 12 minutes behind Stinking Bishop, and those of us with experience in answering posts know that means it is highly likely you had started before Stinking Bishop had posted.

Answer (score 2):

Not a new answer, just an illustration of the arguments concerning even- & oddness of the sum-values in some comments.
Let the unknown base-values, which get pairwise summed denote as $x_1 .. x_4$. Then the six pairwise sums as $s_1...s_6$ . Then let's look at the full multiplication table which occurs when we only look at the residues $(\text{mod } 2)$ (=even- and oddness). We do not find a solution with exactly $1$ odd and $5$ even results for the sums in the complete multiplication table:

[image: picture]